# Using JQuery to switch css

Tags: jquery

I'm switching stylesheets dynamically and noticing that when I choose a different theme only the stylesheet I've chosen is loaded and seems to overwrite all of the other stylesheets. I need to be able to retain 3 other stylesheets but would like to dynamically change just one of them.

Is this possible?

```
$("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : 'themes/' + theme + '.css'});
```

I know next to nothing about JQuery but I think that this `("link[rel=stylesheet]")` is where I'd make such a change but don't know what to change it to so that only one stylesheet is changed.

Comment: you missed `'` before `themes/`

Comment: Thanks M1K1O. That accounted for at least one of my errors. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an id attribute to the link element you want to change like

```
<link id="mylink" .... />
```

then use id-selector

```
$("#mylink").attr({href : 'themes/' + theme + '.css'});
```

Comment: Arun, thanks. I'm using a select on this so would I just add the id to that?

Comment: @user1709311 yes... as an id attribute to the link elements whose ref value you want to change and use it in the id selector

Comment: Got it my friend. Thank you very much. I'll accept this answer when the timer expires. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Put an id to the link which you want to change and then try $('link#your_new_id')

Answer (score 0):

Name the link with class name or id:

```
<link class="nameoflink" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("link.nameoflink").attr({href: 'themes/'+theme+'.css'});
```